# How to disable smilies in Thunderbird?

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, smiles

My Thunderbird e-mail client has a very wrong habbit. In version 13.0.1 on my Windows 7 there is annoying thing I do not know how to disable. When I press

```
ALT + <number>
```

It generates smilies - Is there any way how to disable this generation of smilies? I have some usefull hotkeys using ALT + some numbers and this is crossing my way. Thank you.

Comment: How odd, I have the same version on Win 7 also but mine doesn't do this. Have you checked through your Add Ons? There might be something extra in there.

Comment: I do not have any just quickText addon and virtual identity.

Comment: does this happen in wordpad or notepad as well?

Comment: In notepad yes in wordpad no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options > Advanced > Config Editor > search:"emoticons" > Rightclick > Modify
```

Then add "(off)" or something to the end. That works by stopping Thunderbird from finding the emoticons. Little bit of a Quick and Dirty Hack though.

*Note: You can just delete the text, but I think it's better to be able to reverse it.*

Answer (score 4):

Go to menu "Tools - Options", choose "Display", then "Formatting". Uncheck "Display emoticons as graphics". Confirm with "OK".

Comment: This is just showing emoticons already wrote in text form not solving my problem with ALT button ...

Comment: Might not be answering the question body, but it answered the question title. I found this page through Google and it helped me. Thanks David!

Comment: @Byakugan: Your title doesn't accurately describe your question, however.

Comment: This seems now to be at `Edit > Preferences > Display > Plain Text Messages`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are referirng to a Windows feature which has nothing to do with Thunderbird.

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>numbers</kbd> on the keypad, Windows inserts the character with that code. (It only works with the dedicated numeric keypad.)

But I came across this question because Thunderbird converts some text smileys to emojis when displaying messages. If a mail contains `:-)`, Thunderbird displays it as a graphic smiley : .

This can be disabled by the preference mentioned in David's reply, or with the corresponding preference in your `prefs.js` file:

```
user_pref("mail.display_glyph", false);
```